# How to generate JSLint report in html file format?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jslint4java

Am using JSLint to check the javascript code quality and used the following command to generate the report in html file.

```
C:\Windows\System32>jslint "D:\Work\Settings.js" > "D:\Work\output.html"
```

Output format for the above command as below.

```
D:\Work\Settings.js

 #1 '$' was used before it was defined.

$(document).ready(function () { // Line 1, Pos 1

 #2 'document' was used before it was defined.

$(document).ready(function () { // Line 1, Pos 3
```

But, the report generated contains normal plain text content. So, i want to generate the report in html file format. Is there any other way to generate the JSLint output report in html file format?

Could anyone please provide your suggestion on this?

Comment: Can anyone please update on this?

Comment: First, nobody will be notified if you comment on your own question. ;^) Secondly, there are lots of ways to do this, but they involve coding on your part. You could edit [JSLint itself](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint). You could wrap the call in a bat file, and post-parse it. You could post-process by wrapping JSLint in [JavaScript of your own](http://myfreakinname.blogspot.com/2014/11/jslint-locally-now-in-html.html), which is probably your best bet. What specifically are you looking to do?